# Stars and bars with distance constraints

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

Given $s$ stars and $b$ bars, is there a closed formula to calculate the number of arrangements such that no star is within $k$ of any other star? Similarly, how many arrangements are there such that all stars are within $k$ of any other star?

There is an easy recursion for each of the above:

$$
f_{\texttt{k apart}}(s, b) = 
\begin{align*}
    \begin{cases}
     0 \quad\quad  b \leq -k\\
     1 \quad\quad  s = 0 \\
     \sum_{i=0}^{b} f_{\texttt{k apart}}(s-1,b-i-k)
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$
$$
f_{\texttt{k within}}(s, b) = 
\begin{align*}
    \begin{cases}
     0 \quad\quad  b < 0\\
     1 \quad\quad  s = 0\quad \texttt{or} \quad b = 0\\
     \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} f_{\texttt{k within}}(s-1,b-i)
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$

However, I'm interested in closed solutions, as I will need these values for large numbers and for many different $k$. I'm also happy to split into two separate posts if desired.